# Not Able To Iterate over paged rows in Playwright C#

Tags: c#, playwright

I am trying the iterate over all row pages via a pagination features on a website with Playwright C#. There are 8 pages on the website. Every page contains a list of devices in a table. I figured there is a value which contains the total number of devices. Since every page can contain at most 10 devices, I figured I can make use of this and calculate the total number of pages.

Once I have done that, I feed the number of pages into a for loop and a try to click on every page to get all the device data from that page. Sometimes however the for loop ends at page 6, sometimes it ends on page 8, I suppose due to the asynchronous nature of Playwright.

I hoped that with the await keyword in the click event it would work, but I suppose the for loop is simply faster? I am new to Playwright and async functions, so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

I have also tried to break to code into different async functions, since I need to wait for some code to execute before continuing, but I still was not able to resolver the for loop issue.

Only things that worked a bit was putting a Thread Sleep at the end of the loop, but I am not sure, if this a correct approach.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Playwright;

namespace PlaywrightTests.Pom;
public class Devices
{
  private readonly IPage _page;
  private readonly ILocator _searchField;

  private readonly ILocator _goButton;

  private readonly ILocator _previousPageButton;

  private readonly ILocator _table;

  private readonly ILocator _totalNumberOfDevicesElement;

  public Devices(IPage page)
  {
    _page = page;
    _searchField = page.GetByPlaceholder("Search");
    _goButton = page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Button, new() { Name = "Go" });
    _previousPageButton = page.GetByLabel("Previous");
    _table = page.Locator("//*[@id='tblList']");
    _totalNumberOfDevicesElement = page.Locator("//div[@class='row ng-star-inserted']/div/span");
  }

    public async Task<double> CalculateNumberOfPages(string numberOfDevices) {
        // Dummy click on an element which succeeds the element containing the number of devices, to make sure that the number of devices item loaded completely
        await _previousPageButton.ClickAsync();
        int pFrom = numberOfDevices.IndexOf("of ") + "of ".Length;
        int pTo = numberOfDevices.LastIndexOf(" items");
        numberOfDevices = numberOfDevices.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
        double devicesNumber = Convert.ToDouble(numberOfDevices);
        double numberOfPages = Math.Ceiling(devicesNumber / 10);
        return numberOfPages;
    }

    public async Task IterateOverPages(double nmbrOfPages) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= nmbrOfPages; i++) {
         var singlePage = _page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Link, new() { Name = i.ToString() , Exact = true});
         await singlePage.ClickAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task GoThroughPages() {
        string totalNumberOfDevices = await _totalNumberOfDevicesElement.InnerTextAsync();
        double convertedTotalNumber = await CalculateNumberOfPages(totalNumberOfDevices);
        await IterateOverPages(convertedTotalNumber);
    }
} here
```

Comment: No, async has nothing to do with this. If the *server* is too slow, the browser will go on and render the HTML it got up to that point. Playwright will see only the rendered rows. Playwright already awaits for the network to be idle for a while and the DOM to finish rendering